# How should an HTTP server respond to a proxy request it doesn't wish to handle?

Tags: http, proxy

An HTTP request's first line contains a "target", which is one of the following:

```
request-target = origin-form
               / absolute-form
               / authority-form
               / asterisk-form
```

`origin-form` is the typical one, e.g., `GET /hello-world HTTP/1.1`. A proxy request uses the `absolute-form`:

```
GET https://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

Assume that that request reaches an origin server, that's just trying to serve some *other* domain. (e.g., say we sent the above request to `en.wikipedia.org`.) The server at hand does not wish to be a proxy server, and does not want to fulfill the request as issued. What **should** it return? (And ideally, why? Is there anywhere in HTTP RFC that states this?)

(I queried a few servers to see what empirically happens. I got a mix of mostly 500s, 200s (but with the wrong content), a `409 Conflict` and in one special case, a `301 Moved Permanently` that formed an infinite loop. *I* feel that it is an error on the part of the client to send a proxy request to a server that cannot, and will not fulfill it. Nothing is wrong with the server nor its behavior, and the area where change should be effected lies squarely on the client, thus, 4xx, but it's unclear to me which is appropriate.)

Answer (score 2):

Good question. From [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> 5.1.2 Request-URI
>
> ...
>
> To allow for transition to absoluteURIs in all requests in future
>      versions of HTTP, all HTTP/1.1 servers MUST accept the absoluteURI
>      form in requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only generate
>      them in requests to proxies.

and:

> 5.2 The Resource Identified by a Request
>
> The exact resource identified by an Internet request is determined by
>      examining both the Request-URI and the Host header field.
>
> An origin server that does not allow resources to differ by the
>      requested host MAY ignore the Host header field value when
>      determining the resource identified by an HTTP/1.1 request. (But see
>      section 19.6.1.1 for other requirements on Host support in HTTP/1.1.)
>
> An origin server that does differentiate resources based on the host
>      requested (sometimes referred to as virtual hosts or vanity host
>      names) MUST use the following rules for determining the requested
>      resource on an HTTP/1.1 request:
>
> 1. If Request-URI is an absoluteURI, the host is part of the
>       Request-URI. Any Host header field value in the request MUST be
>       ignored.
> 2. If the Request-URI is not an absoluteURI, and the request includes
>       a Host header field, the host is determined by the Host header
>       field value.
> 3. If the host as determined by rule 1 or 2 is not a valid host on
>       the server, the response MUST be a 400 (Bad Request) error message.

So it looks like the correct answer is either to ignore the host and just try to fulfil the request locally, letting that generate whatever error it may, or else to send 400. This isn't entirely conclusive, as the error is in the GET line, not the HOST line, and yours isn't 'an origin server that does differentiate resources based on the host requested', but it seems as close as the RFC gets.

Of the successor RFCs, [RFC 7230](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7230.txt) has the same wording as 5.1.2 above; it doesn't have anything like section 5.2 that I could find, but it does have this:

> Recipients of an invalid request-line SHOULD respond with either a
>      400 (Bad Request) error or a 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect with
>      the request-target properly encoded.